# linq query proper way to filter

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a flat table (call it t1) thats like this

```
a1 b1 c1 v1 
a1 b1 c1 v2
a1 b1 c2 v4
a1 b1 c3 v3
a1 b1 c3 v4
```

Suppose i want to filter by the last column and i look for v1. Is there a way to write the linq query such that, i also get the second row in the result set ? Basically i want all c1's where the filter matched either for v1 or v2 even though only v1 was specified?

Same for c3. if i want to filter for v4, i want the last 2 rows returned in the result set.

Right now i am getting around it, by making another db call on my controller to go and fetch all values for c1 (if c1 was returned from the filter query) before sending it to the view.

Comment: "i want all `c1`'s where the filter matched  either for `v1` or `v2` even though only `v1` was specified?" - so essentially you're only filtering by `c1`?

Comment: essentially yes, but i dont have the upper level table to work with. Thanks!

Comment: @trashr0x I think the OP means they want to find the `c#` for a given `v#` and then get all the rows that match that `c#`.

Comment: What happens if more than one row has `v1`?  Do you want all the C column values for `v1` to be used for filtering?

Comment: within each c#, v# will be unique. Is that what you are asking ?

Comment: Something like `table.Where(x => table.Where(y => y.V = v1).Select(y => y.C).Contains(x.C))`?

Comment: @cableload: juharr is pointing to situation like V4 where c# is c2 and c3.

Comment: @PankajKapare Yes, it should return both c2 and c3 in that case.

Comment: @juharr would it generate a weird long single sql statement ? (with a list of v#'s  OR)

Comment: @cableload That should create a sql query with a sub query similar to `select * from table where C in (select C from table where V = v1)` if `table` is actually the `DbSet` from your `DbContext`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to write the linq query...

If I interpreted the question correctly, I believe the following code block should work (assuming that you have access to all of the relevant data):

```
var filterText = "v4";
var filteredList = yourList.GroupBy(yourItem => yourItem.Third)
        .Where(groupedItem => groupedItem.Any(yourItem => yourItem.Fourth == filterText))
        .SelectMany(matchedItem => matchedItem).ToList()
```

Given "v4" as the filter text, this statement will return

```
a1 b1 c2 v4
a1 b1 c3 v3
a1 b1 c3 v4
```

Given "v1" as the filter text, this statement will return

```
a1 b1 c1 v1
a1 b1 c1 v2
```

A working example can be found [here](http://ideone.com/dH9JRK).

## Explanation

> "I want all c1's where the filter matched either for v1 or v2 even
>   though only v1 was specified?"

This can be easily accomplished by grouping the data by what appears to be the third column (the column with all of the "c"s), then returning all groups that contain a row that has a matching fourth column (the column with all of the "v"s), and then by flattening that result set so you do not have a list of groups. In other words:

1. I first group the objects by `Third` using a `GroupBy()`.
2. Then, `Where()` is used to return "Any" group that has an item with a matching fourth column.
3. At this point, since we have a list of groups (you will see this if you debug the statement), I flatten the result with `SelectMany()`.

## Example

**My interpretation of your data set:**

```
public class Foo
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Second { get; set; }
    public string Third { get; set; }
    public string Fourth { get; set; }
}
```

**Setup of the data:**

```
var yourList = new List<Foo>()
{
    new Foo(){First = "a1", Second="b1", Third="c1", Fourth="v1"},
    new Foo(){First = "a1", Second="b1", Third="c1", Fourth="v2"},
    new Foo(){First = "a1", Second="b1", Third="c2", Fourth="v4"},
    new Foo(){First = "a1", Second="b1", Third="c3", Fourth="v3"},
    new Foo(){First = "a1", Second="b1", Third="c3", Fourth="v4"}
};
```

**Filtering code:**

```
var filterText = "v4";

var filteredList = yourList.GroupBy(yourItem => yourItem.Third)
    .Where(groupedItem => groupedItem.Any(yourItem => yourItem.Fourth == filterText))
    .SelectMany(matchedItem => matchedItem).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Let say you have a table called `Table` with columns `A, B, C, V`, `db` is an instance of your derived `DbContext` and `v` is variable holding the search criteria for column `V`.

Here are practically all the possible LINQ queries producing the desired result with a single SQL query:

(A) Using `GroupBy`, filtering the groups and flattening the result using `SelectMany` (mentioned in @Joshua Miller answer):

```
var queryA = db.Table
    .GroupBy(e => e.C)
    .Where(g => g.Any(e => e.C == v))
    .SelectMany(g => g);
```

(B) Using self `Join` with `Where`:

```
var queryB = db.Table
    .Join(db.Table.Where(e2 => e2.V == v), e1 => e1.C, e2 => e2.C, (e1, e2) => e1);
```

(C) Using self join with composite key:

```
var queryC = db.Table
    .Join(db.Table, e1 => new { e1.C, V = v }, e2 => new { e2.C, e2.V }, (e1, e2) => e1);
```

(D) Using `Where` with `Any` condition:

```
var queryD = db.Table
    .Where(e1 => db.Table.Any(e2 => e2.C == e1.C && e2.V == v));
```

(E) Using `Where` with `Select` + `Contains` condition (mentioned by @juharr in comments):

```
var queryE = db.Table
    .Where(e1 => db.Table.Where(e2 => e2.V == "v1").Select(e2 => e2.C).Contains(e1.C));
```

So which one to choose?

In LINQ to Objects, (A), (B) and (C) have similar O(N) time complexity, while (D)
and (E) are not good due to O(N^2) time complexity.

In LINQ to Entities (EF6) the picture is slightly different:

(A) Is not good because it translates to horrible SQL involving 3 times `Table` access paths.

(B) and (C) translate to `Table` self `INNER JOIN` and practically are one and the same.

(D) and (E) translate to exactly one and the same SQL query with `EXISTS` clause.

So, (A) should be avoided for sure, and the rest should generate one and the same execution plan by nowadays SQL query optimizers, hence which one you choose should be a matter of taste. You should still take a look at the execution plan and measure the performance though.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation including the performance consideration.

Comment: You are welcome. At least in EF6 you have a choice. If you were on EF Core (currently), the question would be which one executes at all w/o throwing weird internal exceptions :)

Comment: If i need to multiple filters, for example get me a resultset that has both v3 and v4 ? (in the above example, resultset would be a1 b1 c3) is that possible to achieve?

Comment: I think it is possible in all variants except (C) by using appropriate `||` condition. Probably (B) is also inappropriate because it will generate duplicates. So I guess the choice would be between (A), (D) and (E), I would personally select (D) like `.Where(e1 => db.Table.Any(e2 => e2.C == e1.C && (e2.V == v1 || e2.V == v2)));`